# Render keyframe with changed location without applying it

Tags: rendering, transforms, keyframes, error, meta-objects

Simple project with my problem:

- I create a new project
- I insert a keyframe in 0
- I duplicate that object with same keyframe
- I move my new object to random X location
  now I see both in viewport:
  [image]

but when I render i just see 1 because they are render in the keyframe not in like in the viewport.
[image]

Complex problem:
I have a metaball with x keyframes with diferent positions and I want to interpolate that keyframes with linear, Hermite...
When I create more metaballs, copying the original keyframes and applying random location it  shows in 3D View but not in render.
[image]

This is a work from college and profesor said we can't add or change original keyframes so I'm not able to solve it that way.
[image]

Thank you in advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying an object which has keyframes, the keyframes will be copied too. The keyframes "define" the location and Blender will automatically calculate the position for you. You can verify that by pressing Spacebar to start the animation. The copied object will "jump" immediately to your keyframed value. You can stop this by

- deleting the keyframe of the new object
- overwriting the keyframe with a new value

When rendering Blender calculates these positions again. That's why you don't see them (because they are on the same position).

Explanation of the colors when keyframing them:

Grey - no keyframes at all.
[image]

Yellow - keyframes at current frame.
[image]

Green - no keyframes at current frame.
[image]

Orange - properties changed but unsaved.
[image]

With metaballs You need to create different metaball objects but not multiple balls in one metaball.

[image]

Comment: The problem I found is that renders set's atributes to 0 (deafult every frame) and when is setted that frame works but in the next it reset to 0

I have: 
if (frame_desp % obj.frec) == 1:
        obj.rand_val[coord] = (np.random.random()-0.5)(obj.m_max2)

this works only in keyframes when % = 1 and in the other don't work. The stranger think is that it works in 3d view but not in render....

Comment: May be you can share you blender file [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help). I can't clearly understand what do yo do?